# Conditional url in Handlebar template

Tags: handlebars.js

I have a SPA made with Handlebars, the templates are file ending with html extension. I want to run the app on localhost, and replace the url in src attribute with "localhost". It's easy to do in the Js files, but how to do it in html files?

```
<img alt="header contact" border="0" align="top" src="http://example.com/app/email_tmpl/img/header-contact.jpg">
```

Comment: I think you should just use relative URLs. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21828923/3397771

Comment: of course,  why didn't I think about that, thanks.